# Is there a no-copy buffer/stream in the C# other than MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a class which, rather than copying data written to it into an internal array which is occasionally resized (as `MemoryStream` does), retains a reference to each buffer that users pass into it on write, and maintains a data structure which keeps track of each buffer written and the offset/count? It should also support a read mechanism which will provide clients with a buffer, offset, and count (rather than requiring clients to allocate and provide a buffer into which the data is copied for each read).

Essentially I need something which retains data by reference and doesn't do any significant allocations or any data copying behind my back. For some reason I doubt the BCL provides this. Any known implementations?

Comment: Are you looking for performance improvements?  How much improvement do you need?

Comment: You can use the MemoryStream constructor that takes a capacity, if you are worried about resizing a lot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489.aspx

Comment: This is in a server application—the system copies the data from the kernel to user space, and then into managed memory, and want to be able to conveniently pass it around in managed code without ever copying it in managed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a

```
List<ArraySegment<byte>>
```

do?

Comment: That's handy; I didn't know about the ArraySegment struct. It's not a full implementation of what I want, but definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: ArraySegment<> doesn't store anything.

Comment: The more I think about it, I'm not sure that what I asked for is exactly what I want. But whatever it is that I end up with, it will involve ArraySegment. Thanks.